# Laptop won't start after changing flex / LVDS cable

Tags: laptop

few days ago it started "smoking" from left down corner from my laptop. When I disassembled my laptop, I've discovered that display cable is burned. I unplugged that from motherboard and few times I could start laptop. Now it does not work anymore. I've bought new cable and changed that and I can't start my laptop. When I want to charge my laptop, led diod won't even light up.
How can I solve that? Thanks.
Laptop is HP G7000.

Comment: It's broken. Take it to a repair shop or buy a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The flat flex cable isnt the problem.  Something failed on the motherboard that burned the cable.  If the laptop is under warranty, send it in for service.  If it isnt, then you can try a reputable repair shop and they *might* be able to fix it.  Otherwise, the laptop is dead.